# IOS Cordova Push Plugin - Coldstart Crashes App

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am using the the Cordova Push Plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

This works fine in Android Platform. But, for IOS, I face the following issue:
I register listener for '$cordovaPush:notificationReceived' event as per the documentation and provide the same implementation as given in the documentation in the link above (given below for ease):

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
  if (notification.alert) {
    navigator.notification.alert(notification.alert);
  }

  if (notification.sound) {
    var snd = new Media(event.sound);
    snd.play();
  }

  if (notification.badge) {
    $cordovaPush.setBadgeNumber(notification.badge).then(function(result) {
      // Success!
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
    });
  }
});
```

There are 3 scenarios: 
1. App is running in foreground. In such case, even though the notification arrives (confirmed by log statements), no visible action happens on the device. 
I expected the below two statements to execute but they dont.

```
navigator.notification.alert(notification.alert);
snd.play();
```

2. App is running in background. In such case, the statements seem to execute as per expected behaviour.
3. App is NOT running at all (coldstart). In this case, the notification and sound are played but when user click on notification, the app opens and hangs / crashes.

Has anyone encountered these problems before? What is the best way to solve these? This is only for IOS.

Comment: I would suggest  you to install https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push , because the plugin you are using is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using is deprecated.

i also used it before and there are many issues.

i would reccomend to use the plugin: [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

easy to install and will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Nechemya Kanelsky, use the newer version of the push plugin and scenario 1 and 2 will be handled. But with that plugin as well, the 3rd issue still remains, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/50)

You can use the fix for 3rd issue, mentioned [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/50#issuecomment-203801800)